# Update items in a list based on another list

Tags: python, list, insert-update

I have a list which contains names, position and points, then there is an new list which I manage to get the data's from a game api, loops it and appends it after that it will empty the newlist and rinse repeat (in my example I won't put the api loop code instead I will put the kind of data I get to make it simple)

```
list = [
        ['Charlie', '3', '2000'],
        ['Bill', '2', '2100'],
        ['Alan', '1', '2200']
        ]

newlist = [
        ['Charlie', '3', '2300'],
        ['Bill', '2', '2350'],
        ['Alan', '1', '2400']
        ]

#doesn't work as mentioned previously  
list.append(updatedlist)

print(list)
```

So all I need is to update the new list to the main list, as you can see, for a given name-position pair, the score changes in the new list.

I want the original list to reflect the updated scores. How can I do this?

Comment: I am a bit confused. Do you want to update the players' records based on the new result? If so, can you try a dffirent data structure such as pandas.DataFrame?

Comment: Tuples are immutable. Use something else, or replace it entirely.

Comment: what is your expected output

Comment: Is the elements of both lists in the same order as you have mentioned in the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One fundamental assumption is that, in your use case, `lst` (don't use `list` to name your objects) is certainly much bigger than `newlist`, and not all entries are subject to update (or else you could've just done `lst = newlist`).

Another assumption here is that the first two elements in a tuple form the "key", and the last element forms the "value" for each entry. We'll use this setup for our solution.

A brute force solution would involve a nested loop and run in quadratic time. You can hash your data and reduce this to a linear operation, using an `OrderedDict` to maintain order.

Let the dictionary handle the update for you.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

# initialise an ordered dictionary from your existing data
o = OrderedDict((v[:-1], v[-1]) for v in lst)
# initialise an ordered dictionary from your new data
o_new = OrderedDict((v[:-1], v[-1]) for v in newlist)
# update current entries with new/updated entries 
o.update(o_new)

lst_updated = [k + (v, ) for k, v in o.items()]
```

```
print(lst_updated)
[('Charlie', '3', '2300'), ('Bill', '2', '2350'), ('Alan', '1', '2400')]
```

Comment: I see, on the scale of this will there be performance issue if I put in a loop with big list? or multi threading will be needed?

Comment: @user7716943 Complexity wise, this is a very performant solution - it is O(n), linear in complexity. It should work with reasonably large lists without any issue. Don't look at multithreading until you've already implemented the basics algorithm.

Comment: @user7716943 what will be the R code for this ?